# Using Castle Windsor WCF facility with WCF 4 REST service gives 'Could not find a component' error

Tags: wcf, rest, castle-windsor, castle

As a long time reader of StackOverflow but not finding the solution to my problem here is my first attempt to ask a question, so don't be too harsh on me :-)

I have the following WCF 4 REST service definitions:

Service contract

```
namespace RestService2.Service
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ISampleService
    {
       [WebGet(UriTemplate = "")]
       List<SampleItem> GetCollection();

       [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "", Method = "POST")]
       SampleItem Create(SampleItem instance);

       [WebGet(UriTemplate = "?id={id}")]
       SampleItem Get(int id);

       [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "?id={id}", Method = "PUT")]
       SampleItem Update(int id, SampleItem instance);

       [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "?id={id}", Method = "DELETE")]
       void Delete(int id);
    }
}
```

Service implementation

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public class SampleService : ISampleService
{
    private IDatabase db;
    public SampleService(IDatabase db)
    {
        this.db = db;
    }

    public SampleService()
    {
    }
    public List<SampleItem> GetCollection()
    {
        return db.Items.Values.ToList();
    }

    public SampleItem Create(SampleItem instance)
    {
        // Add the new instance of SampleItem to the collection
        db.Items.Add(instance.Id, instance);
        return db.Items[instance.Id];
    }

    //..Rest omitted..
}
```

Database interface:

```
using RestService2.Entities;

namespace RestService2.Service
{
   public interface IDatabase
   {
      Dictionary<int, SampleItem> Items { get; }

   }
}
```

Database implementation:

```
public class Database : IDatabase
{
    private Dictionary<int, SampleItem> items;

    public Database()
    {
    }

    public Dictionary<int, SampleItem> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return items;
        }
    }
}
```

..and the global.asax file

```
namespace RestService2.Web
{
    public class Global : HttpApplication
    {
        static IWindsorContainer Container {get; set;}

        void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           BuildContainer();
           RegisterRoutes();
        }

        private void BuildContainer()
        {
           Container = new WindsorContainer();
           Container.AddFacility<WcfFacility>()
            .Register(Component.For<ISampleService>().ImplementedBy<SampleService>().Named("SampleService"))
            .Register(Component.For<IDatabase>().ImplementedBy<Database>());

        }
        private void RegisterRoutes()
        {
            RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("SampleService",
            new DefaultServiceHostFactory(), typeof(SampleService)));
        }
    }
}
```

The service contract, service implementation, database interface and database implementation are in assembly A, SampleItem (an entity) is defined in assembly B and the global.asax.cs is in assembly C.

I have added references from assembly A and B to assembly C.

When I try to access the service help page (or any service method for that matter) I get the following error message: `Could not find a component with type RestService2.Service.SampleService, RestService2.Service, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, did you forget to register it?`

Any idea what could be problem? How should i configure the container correctly?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to build a REST service using the WCFIntegration facility, using both interfaces for registration and through the MVC routing mechanism.

```
// SVC Routes
routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("Example", new WindsorServiceHostFactory<RestServiceModel>(), typeof(IExample)));
```

Remember to register the service/implementation in Windsor before calling `RegisterRoutes` (where this code would be). Additionally, make sure you call this route registration before your default route, otherwise that will be used instead.

The service can then just be called via the route, ie:

```
http://localhost:80/Core/Example/GetAll/
```

Answer (score 1):

since you registered the routing by concrete type

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("SampleService", 
            new DefaultServiceHostFactory(), typeof(SampleService)));
```

and as far as I remember you cannot do otherwise... I mean you cannot register by interface, you need to register into the container by concrete as well

instead of

```
 .Register(Component.For<ISampleService>().ImplementedBy<SampleService>().Named("SampleService"))
```

try

```
 .Register(Component.For<SampleService>().Named("SampleService"))
```

Comment: When I try this and I try to access the help page (with the list of operations) in a browser I get a blank page. I added another route with the 'standard' host factory: RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("SampleServiceStd", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(SampleService))); and here the help page DOES work. Any ideas?

Comment: After trying and trying to get it working without result, I decided to abandon the WCF facility and use the method described in [link](http://codebetter.com/howarddierking/2010/01/19/vanilla-yet-composable-http-services-with-wcf-4-and-windsor/). This works for me, but it's still a pity that I didn't get the WCF facility correctly working. It's also a pity that there is a lack of documentation for this particular facility